# Permanenetly change type of object in VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net, casting, type-conversion

I have the following:

```
Public Class OldClass
    Inherits NewClass
    ....
End Class
```

`NewClass` Inherits from `BaseClass`

Now I have a `list(Of BaseClass)`

I am deserializing a few of these objects from XML. The XML could contain both `OldCLass`es and `NewCLass`es.

After deserialization the objects are in the list.

`OldClass` is *exactly* the same as `NewClass` (the only code in `OldClass` is `Inherits NewClass`). I had to create the old class because the element name changed in the XML and I need to maintain backwards compatibility.

How can I permanently change the type of any `OldClass` objects in the `list` so that when they are re-serialized, they become `<NewClass ...>` instead of `<OldClass ...>`?

I have tried `CType`, `OldClass.ChangeType`, `list(list.indexOf(OldTypeObj)).ChangeType(...)`... Nothing works. When debugging, inspecting the list shows that the `OldClass`es are still just that.

**EDIT**

I am using this to serialize the existing data:

```
<XmlArray("lines")> _
<XmlArrayItem("CalculatedLine", GetType(Lines.CalculatedLine))> _
<XmlArrayItem("PointLine", GetType(Lines.PointLine))> _
<XmlArrayItem("line", GetType(Lines.OldLine))> _ <<This needs to become PointLine when serialized.
Public Property lines As List(Of Lines.Line) = New List(Of Lines.Line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the `XmlSerializer`? Apparently [(see MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) you can override the definition of the class name as the root of the XML document by using the `XmlRootAttribute` in your class definition, which might help? Example below -

First the class definitions. The `XMLRoot` is declared as `ClassNew`, so any `ClassOld` objects will be serialized to XML with the root `ClassNew`, and so reserialized into `ClassNew` objects -

```
Public Class ClassBase
    Public Property name As String
End Class

Public Class ClassNew
    Inherits ClassBase
End Class

<XmlRoot("ClassNew")>
Public Class ClassOld
    Inherits ClassNew
End Class
```

So to test it first serialize the objects (which may be the old or the new class) -

```
    Dim objectListBefore As New List(Of ClassBase)
    objectListBefore.Add(New ClassOld)
    objectListBefore.Add(New ClassNew)

    Dim nameList = New List(Of String)

    For Each item In objectListBefore
        item.name = Guid.NewGuid.ToString
        nameList.Add(item.name)
        Dim objStreamWriter As New StreamWriter(String.Format("C:\Temp\{0}.xml", item.name))
        Dim xmlSerialiser1 As New XmlSerializer(item.GetType)
        xmlSerialiser1.Serialize(objStreamWriter, item)
        objStreamWriter.Close()
    Next
```

And then deserialize to the new class -

```
    Dim objectListAfter As New List(Of ClassBase)
    Dim classNewObject As New ClassNew
    Dim xmlSerialiser2 As New XmlSerializer(classNewObject.GetType)

    For Each name In nameList
        Dim objStreamReader As New StreamReader(String.Format("C:\Temp\{0}.xml", name))
        Dim myOtherObject As New ClassNew()
        myOtherObject = CType(xmlSerialiser2.Deserialize(objStreamReader), ClassNew)
        objectListAfter.Add(myOtherObject)
        objStreamReader.Close()
    Next

End Sub
```